# How do I add a picture from the internet as a background for my app?

Tags: image, swiftui, background, xcode15

I want a picture from the internet that I have downloaded to be a background for a specific part of my homepage that I am working on.

This is my homepage code:

```
struct LaunchPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            GeometryReader {geo in
                VStack{
                    ScrollView{
                    ZStack {
                        Color.clear
                            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        NavigationLink("Groups", destination: GroupPage())
                            .font(.title.weight(.bold))
                            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 20)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(height: 70)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                       
                        NavigationLink("Calendar", destination: CalendarPage())
                            .font(.title.weight(.bold))
                            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 140)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(height: 70)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                        
                        NavigationLink("Join", destination: JoinPage())
                            .font(.title.weight(.bold))
                            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 300)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(height: 70)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Image("carpooly-high-resolution-logo")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 2.0, height: geo.size.width * 1.5)
                                .offset(y:-88)
                                .offset(x:-200)
                                .padding(.top, 100)
                    }
                    }.background(backgroundGradient)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

I already have backgrounds set for the navbar area but I want one for the middle of the screen. This is currently how the launchpage looks: [image: Launchpage]

The white space with the Carpooly logo is where I want the background to be.

I have not really tried anything and I have searched the web and couldn't find anything. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You have downloaded a picture from the Internet. Do you have an appropriate licence to use it this way? Just because an image is on the Internet, it doesn't mean it's in the public domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an image as the background to your logo image, you could try this approach,
using a simple `ZStack` with the image you have from the internet.

Example code:

```
 VStack {
     Spacer()
     ZStack {  // <--- here
         
         Image("internet_image")  // <--- here image from internet
             .resizable()
             .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) // adjust as required
             //...
         
         Image("carpooly-high-resolution-logo")
             .resizable()
             .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              //...

     } // end ZStack
 } // end VStack
```

Comment: let me try this thank you!

Comment: i also want to add the logo to the top with the navbar next to groups and calendar and join how would i do that?

Comment: If space allows it, just add your logo image after the "Join" NavigationLink.
 Such as: `Image("carpooly-high-resolution-logo").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40)`

Comment: ok perfect thank you so much again.